# Is EventHandler.BeginInvoke "safe" to use?

Tags: c#, events

I have a class that watches over motor status. Sometimes I raise an event but I want to raise it on another thread. What is the best (and safest) way to achieve this ?

Is this method safe if an exception is thrown in the handler ? Is it even "legal" to do so ?

```cs
public class MyMotorManager
{
    public event EventHandler<InputStateChangedEventArgs> MotorEnabledChanged;

    private void RaiseMyEvent(bool newEnableValue)
    {
        InputStateChangedEventArgs e = new InputStateChangedEventArgs(newEnableValue);
        MotorEnabledChanged?.BeginInvoke(this, e, MotorEnabledChanged.EndInvoke, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: How could you? you will be going to court as the accused

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary well I don't want any trouble your honnor. I'm not quite sure I know all about the laws in event raising and delegates and wouldn't want to be suited for anything I did wrong...

Comment: it may be kinda inconvenient - you might just want to use `QueueUserWorkItem`? However, in **all** cases involving threads, the method being invoked needs to catch and handle its own exceptions. With `QueueUserWorkItem`, it is relatively easy to wrap that in an inline lambda.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks I will use that one then.